# SQL using Group by with COUNT

Tags: sql, aggregate

I have a field with 2 similar values but different spelling.
Eg:

```
Article_Name | Articles_ID
------------------------------
Pen          |       P_1
Bottle       |       B_2
Botle        |       B_3
Pen          |       P_2
```

I want a total for each category. I use COUNT for this.
If I do

```
SELECT CASE WHEN article_ID = 'Pen'
              THEN 'Pen'
            WHEN (article_ID = 'Bottle' OR article_ID = 'Botle')
            Then 'Bottle'
       else Article_ID
       END
       ,COUNT(Article_id) as total
From Table_name
Group by Article_ID
```

This gives me 2 different counts for Bottle. I want a total sum for all bottles.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to aggregate by the complete `case` expression:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN article_ID = 'Pen' THEN 'Pen'
             WHEN article_ID IN ('Bottle', 'Botle') THEN 'Bottle'
             ELSE Article_ID
        END) as new_article_id,
       COUNT(*) as total
FROM Table_name
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN article_ID = 'Pen' THEN 'Pen'
               WHEN article_ID IN ('Bottle', 'Botle') THEN 'Bottle'
               ELSE Article_ID
          END);
```

Some databases would also allow you to write one of these:

```
GROUP BY new_article_id
GROUP BY 1
```

An aggregation query with `GROUP BY` returns one row per unique combination of keys.  The `CASE` expression is then evaluated *after* the aggregation, which is why you are getting multiple rows.